# Entity subclass with no attributes

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm

I am using JPA 2.0 in my project.

I have and entity subclass AppEntity extends AbstractEntity.

AbstractEntity is mapped with @MappedSuperClass, which has

```
@Id
@Column(name ="OBJID")
private String objId;

@Column
...(other entities)
along with getters and setters for objId and other attributes.
```

In my subclass AppEntity all the setter methods are overridden.
subclass entity does not have any attributes (@Id / @Column mappings).

When I deploy this application using hibernate 4.2.6

I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException because org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder checks for at server startup

```
private static PropertyData getUniqueIdPropertyFromBaseClass(
            .....
    //Id properties are on top and there is only one
            return baseClassElements.get( 0 );
}
```

Since the subclass entity does not have any attributes get(0) throws Outofbound exception.

But the above code work in JPA 1.0 since hibernate 3.5 does not have above check.

In JPA 2.0 is there any restrictions on subclass entities?
What logic behind checking the attributes in AnnotationBinder.java getUniqueIdPropertyFromBaseClass method.

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationBinder.java

Adding StackTrace for reference

```
AnnotationBinder.getUniqueIdPropertyFromBaseClass(PropertyData, PropertyData, AccessType, Mappings) line: 2576  
AnnotationBinder.isIdClassPkOfTheAssociatedEntity(ElementsToProcess, XClass, PropertyData, PropertyData, AccessType, Map<XClass,InheritanceState>, Mappings) line: 925  
AnnotationBinder.mapAsIdClass(Map<XClass,InheritanceState>, InheritanceState, PersistentClass, EntityBinder, PropertyHolder, ElementsToProcess, Set<String>, Mappings) line: 824    
AnnotationBinder.bindClass(XClass, Map<XClass,InheritanceState>, Mappings) line: 671    
Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue() line: 3533 
Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(List<MetadataSourceType>) line: 3487  
Configuration.secondPassCompile() line: 1376    
Configuration.buildSessionFactory(ServiceRegistry) line: 1777   
EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitTransactionType, boolean, Class, Configuration, ServiceRegistry, String) line: 94    
Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder) line: 920  
Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory() line: 904 
HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo, Map) line: 92 
PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory() line: 200  
PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl) line: 57  
PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run() line: 99 
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Runnable) line: 886   
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 908   
JBossThread(Thread).run() line: 619 
JBossThread.run() line: 122
```